# Error in installing sphinxbase and pocketsphinx in ubuntu

Tags: sphinx

i am trying to install sphinxbase in ubuntu,but i am getting the following error when performing the make install command.

make[4]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/aniruddha/project/sphinxbase-0.8/src/libsphinxbase'
make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/aniruddha/project/sphinxbase-0.8/src/libsphinxbase'
make[2]:**  [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/aniruddha/project/sphinxbase-0.8/src/libsphinxbase'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/aniruddha/project/sphinxbase-0.8/src'
make: ** [install-recursive] Error 1

plz help me out how can i omit these errors..

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same error... putting "sudo" in front of the make install sorted it out. :-)